# Работа с opencart cms

Tags: opencart

Всем привет!

Коротко о сути задания: в opencart установлена стандартная тема, получается так что категории(коллекции) товаров и список одиночных товаров выводятся на одной странице, нужно сделать переключатель, т.е. нажал на кнопку показываются только коллекции товаров, нажал на другую кнопку - появились товары.

Проблема: для того чтобы разграничить вывод товаров и коллекций нужно найти файл контроллера который их выводит, с чем я не могу справится уже три дня, в интернете я прочитал о том, что за вывод товаров и коллекций отвечает файл catalog/controller/product/category.php - вывод товарной группы, дальше я пробовал его редактировать, но ничего не происходило, даже если я весь код в том файле сотру ничего так и не меняется, в нем примерно 550 строк кода на php, т.е. поведение сайта когда category.php пустой и когда в нем 550 строк кода никак не отличается, что для меня очень странно. Но, вдруг если этот файл удалить вообще а не только текст в нем, то товары и коллекции сразу же пропадают, а вместо них появляется сообщение о том что запрашиваемая страница не найдена, во прикол. Значит этот файл и код в нем зачем-то нужны.

Помогите пожалуйста, я уже даже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Дополнительные модули устанавливали? Например, модули фильтров, кэширования?

Comment: Да, а причем тут контроллер? Если кнопку показать\скрыть можно реализовать в файле шаблона вывода category.tpl используя javascript.

Comment: Под "коллекцией товаров" вы подразумеваете список подкатегорий?

Comment: Да, из доп модулей устанавливал mega filter pro, под коллекцией товаров я имею ввиду группу товаров у которых есть общие признаки, в opnecart они располагаются выше товаров. Да, я над эти думал, но есть ли смысл делать такую посредственную реализацию через js, т.е. при каждом изменении фильтра ajax отправляет и категории и товары и приходится удалять что-то одно из html, как по мне гораздо удобней и лучше сделать это через контроллер, или я не прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Почему не помогает редактирование исходников** **`catalog/controller/product/category.php`**:

Т.к. вы используете расширения **vqMod/ocMod**, такие как **filter pro**, оригинальные файлы изменяются и кешируются. И далее они уже читаются из папки **`system/storage/madification/`** для расширений ocMod, и **`coren_sayta/vqmod/vqcache для расширений vqmod`**. Теперь, каждый раз внося изменения в исходники (тот же **`catalog/controller/product/category.php`**), необходимо очищать кеш и обновлять лейаут. Это делается либо руками, удаляя папки/файлы из вышеуказанных хранилищ, либо в админке в меню **`Менеджер дополнений/Modifications`**

Редактировать представление шаблона логичнее в файлах представления (шаблона) :). Т.е. делать всякие переключатели надо не в контроллере, а в **`vash_domen\catalog\view\theme\default(vash_shablon)\template\product\category.tpl`**

З.Ы. Перед рендером, если не выполнить очистку кешей, система проверяет только наличие исходника. От того и "не найдена", если удалить файл.

З.Ы.Ы. Все файлы зачем-то да нужны =)

Comment: Спасибо за информативный ответ(не сарказм).

Comment: Скажите, правильно ли я понял, нужно в папке system/storage/madification/ удалить все файлы, сейчас там такая структура http://joxi.ru/DrlzjbDU4Kkdw2 ? В папке coren_sayta/vqmod/vqcache http://joxi.ru/a2XWvKgIyQKZ1m , что там лежит?

Comment: в общем - да. на скрине ocMod представлена структура изменённых расширениями файлов. Эта структура идентична структуре вашего сайта. Т.е. названия/порядок/вложенность папок одинаковая. А с vqMod надо быть аккуратнее. В названии любого файла кеша vqMod есnть ссылка на файл оригинал, после vq2-. Т.е. если есть сомнения - бейте только файлы, в названиях коротых пресудствует неймспейс файла оригинала (vq2-catalog_view...). HO!!! Начните с очистки кеша из админки, я описывал как. И если не поможет, делайте руками. А перед руками я бы ещё и скинул кеши на хосте.

Comment: По поводу очистки кеша из админки, после того как я кликнул по кнопке редактировать напротив modification manager http://joxi.ru/4Akzj8DUMjBbp2 , появилось вот это http://joxi.ru/v29OVXzSG4kXqr , там примерно 1000 строк кода на php js html(xml), это все нужно стереть?

Comment: нет. на скрине расширение админки, я его не знаю. Я писал не об этом а об этом: http://imgur.com/a/zRmNV

Comment: Ага, понял, далее просто нажать на оранжевую кнопку сброс?

Comment: да, оранжевая > голубая и сайт в браузере обновляйте через ctrl+f5

Comment: нажал я на оранжевую кнопку, все дополнения почему-то удалились и сайт сразу же поменял свой внешний вид

Comment: обновите админку в браузере ctrl+f5. нажмите голубую. Вы галочки не ставили напротив названий в списке расширений?

Comment: Фух, нажал и все стало как было, таким образом обновляются файлы контроллера и шаблона?

Comment: нет, так обновляются файлы расширений. Не оригиналы, копии из тех папок, о которых я писал.

Comment: Т.е. если я в оригинальном файле, скажем catalog/controller/product/category.php внесу строчку echo 'Ура'; она появится в том изменённом расширением файле который хранится в кеше?

Comment: да, но только после всех вышеперечисленных действий.