# Как отключить кэширование в opencart?

Tags: opencart

Делаю правки на сайте с опенкарт, но правки не сразу видно.
Скорее всего включено кэширование.
Подскажите, как отключить кэширование?
В браузере удалял кэш, но изменений всё-равно не видно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opencart** не имеет системы кеширования файлов по-умолчанию. Есть система модификаций ([Работа с opencart cms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706756/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-opencart-cms)), её и называют кешем. Такой кеш работает только! с модифицированными файлами.

Вы столкнулись с **серверным кешированием** и с кешированием через заголовки отправляемые .**htaccess**. Кеш  вторых, в принципе, скидывает банальное ctrl+f5. Первые обнуляются на хосте из панели, хотя тут многое зависит от панели и хоста. Например, хост goDaddy позволяет оперировать серверным кешем через get запрос с сайта.

Comment: хостинг http://www.ukraine.com.ua. Так как тогда обнулять кэш? ctrl+f5 не работает

Comment: /system/library/cache.php. Можно ли в этом классе Cache что-то поменять, чтобы не кешировалось?

Comment: хороший хост. сайт - меню "Настройка сайта" - вкладка "Настройки оптимизации сайта", в самом низу ссылка "Очистить кеш"

Comment: кстати не сработала очистка кеширования. http://clip2net.com/s/3N9tW2u   изменений так и не видно. видно только вчерашние изменения, сегодняшние не видно

Comment: не забывайте, что в браузере старые кеши после последнего обновления. сбросили на хосте - сбросте в браузере и смотрите.

Comment: неа, что-то не то, не видно обновлений, хотя html вчера нормально обновился, js не хочет сейчас обновляться, чистил несколько раз и браузер и этот хост

Comment: вы говорите про модифицированные файлы или нет? если да, то всё в ответе на прошлый вопрос.

Comment: а можно точнее? какой именно ответ? вы имеете ввиду систему модификаций? как её обойти? что с ней делать?

Comment: а зачем? процесс проверки/перезаписи модификаторов занимает время/ресурсы. Наверно это можно перепедалить в движке (будет каждый раз переписывать файлы при запросе любой страницы), но в ущерб производительности системы. Я так не делал, никогда не видел необходимости. Пока занимаетесь отладкой, отключите кеш сервера, закомменьте  expires в .htaccess. Но кеш модификаторов придётся дёргать.

Comment: в файле .htaccess не нашёл expires."кеш модификаторов" Так а где он находится?

Comment: извините, мне показалось что я вам вчера отвечал на вопрос) вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706756/Работа-с-opencart-cms

Comment: это чтобы разработчикам веселей было разрабатывать сделано? :)

Comment: это решение оправданно при большом количестве расширений. Расчёт был такой скорее всего - поставили мага, поставили расширения, запустили в релиз. О разрабах не думали, но это и логично. Опенкарт это интерпрайз а не бета под напильник.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64285/discussion-between-word-and-kirill-korushkin).