# OpenCart, не меняется статус модуля

Tags: php, opencart, модули

Устанавливаю вот такой вот модуль https://opencartforum.com/files/file/1011-dostavka-po-oblastyam-na-karte/ 
, но по какой-то причине не меняется его статус и он не хочет работать. Сначала думал из-за модификация или конфликта с плагинами другими, но на чистом OC с такой же версией как и на демо плагина тоже ничего не работает.

Вот приблизительный порядок в котором я все делаю:

1. Установка OC
2. Копирование папок admin и catalog в каталог с OC
3. Устанавливаю модуль
4. Убеждаюсь, что разрешено редактирование и просмотр
5. Модуль все еще отключен в таблице в поле "Статус"
6. Захожу в редактирование, убеждаюсь, что статус активен и добавляю новую зону - сохраняю
7. Модуль по-прежднему в статусе отключен и ничего не выводится, в том числе отладка в виде "echo" в модели, она так же не выводится, что тоже говорит, что OC просто считает его выключенным.

Я уже уйму времени убил, пытаясь понять, что я делаю не так. Ладно если б на рабочем магазе не работал, но то, что на чистом ОС не работает, это просто уже в голове не укладывается, ведь все делаю как надо, в демо работает, а у меня - нет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Скинь [кеши браузера, проверь серверное кеширование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709380/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-opencart/709406#709406) и [модификаторы магазина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706756/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-opencart-cms). Проверку новых расширений и изменений проводи в Инкогнито.
- Убедись в совместимости модуля и версии **`opencart`**
- В базе, в таблице setting проверить значение статуса данного модуля (key = takoy_to_module_status, val = 0/1)
- Если модуль платный, то разработчик обязан оказывать какую-то поддержку продукта. Поэтому советую стучать к нему, если всё выше перечисленное не поможет.
- **`echo`** в модели не будет выводить на экран. Проверки переменных в модели лучше проводить через логирование **`$this->log->write()`** или при передаче из контроллера.

Comment: 1. Все кеши скидывал, не помогает

Comment: 2. Версия подходит, на сайте модуля указано 2.3.x как и уменя +  демо модуля на той же версии и там он работает. 3. С разработчком связывался, но грубо говоря дал малополезные советы и в итоге сказал, что OC считает его выключенным, больше ничего не говорит. 4. $this->log->write("test") почему-то ничего не выводит даже с контроллера админки, который работает нормально, ведь текст должно вывести в журнале ошибок?

Comment: Кстати говоря в том же модуле "Бесплатная доставка" или "free.php", echo выводит инфу, а мой - нет.

Comment: так же сравнивал файлы, которые разработчик скидывал, они совпадают, то есть модуль в целостности

Comment: так же shipping_maparea_status в контроллере админки выдает 1(true), то есть там модуль считает, что он включен, но на странице модуля стоит статус выключено и я никакими силами не могу его поменять. Я даже сравнивал с тем же контроллером "free.php", алгоритм смены статуса, да и вообще работы, один и тот же, но OC все равно этот модуль не принимает почему-то.

Comment: проблема эта на версии ocStore 2.3.0.2, что на чистом OC, что на самом сайте симптомы одни и те же

Comment: В базе, в таблице setting проверить значение статуса данного модуля (key = takoy_to_module_status, val = 0/1). Если 0, то либо name инпута статуса не совпадает с передаваемым в настойки модуля в контроллере, либо происходит присваивание ноля в контроллере или шаблоне. Как вариант

Comment: Посмотрел, там его нет вовсе, хотя я разработчика спрашивал, не должен ли он та быть, он сказал нет.

Comment: Ну, если бы модуль писался в соответствии с моделью opencart, статус хранился бы  именно там. Тогда смотрите с какой моделью работает контроллер и проверяйте, в каких таблицах записывается модуль и какое значение у статуса. Это всё в admin

Comment: Я покопался, но так и не смог разобраться, посмотрите, пожалуйста, https://pastebin.com/msL1AdPR

Comment: в методе index перед строчкой $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('shipping_maparea', $this->request->post); сделайте вардамп и посмотрите, что улетает в модель (var_dump($this->request->post)).

Comment: И судя по коду, настройки модуля всё же хранятся в таблице setting в поле(полях) с индексом shipping_maparea

Comment: array(7) {
  ["shipping_maparea_tax_class_id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["shipping_maparea_geo_zone_id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["shipping_maparea_status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["shipping_maparea_sort_order"]=>
  string(3) "100"
  ["shipping_maparea_show_map"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["shipping_maparea_set"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["maparea_status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

Comment: Я проверил таблицу еще раз, там с maparea вообще ничего нет

Comment: Значит сетинги модуля не сохраняются в базу. Проверьте в папке system/storage/modification - есть ли там admin/model/setting/setting.php. Если да, покажите листинг.

Comment: Нет, в папке только index.php. Еще примечательный факт, что после установки в настройках модуля он сразу стоит "Включено", хотя любой дргой модуль всегда сначала стоит в "Выключено". Я больше всего не понимаю, как этот модуль работает в демо версии и откуда положительные отзывы, если он такой кривой, может это все-таки у меня руки кривые?

Comment: Что если я Вам его скину, не захотите попытаться установить его, для чистоты эксперемента)?

Comment: public $CONFIG = array(
        'status' => 1, - поэтому он включён при первой загругке Расшарьте архив где-нить.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GfTUNQYYPrGcEmy2ZywJ7foxHNvye5af

Comment: Ну что, у вас тоже не работает?

Comment: Просто интересно, у вас все же получилось запустить его?