# Проблемы с входом в админ панель в Opencart-e

Tags: opencart

Перенёс сайт на другой хост настройл базу данных, сайт работает, но при логирований выдаёт ошибку `No match for Username and/or Password.` хотя все данные есть, и ещё нет кнопки восстановления пароля

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая ошибка часто возникает, когда вы портируетесь на хост, использующий устаревший **mysql** драйрер вместо **mysqli**. Проверить так: `в config.php и admin/config.php` замените:

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
```

на:

```
// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
```

И если получиться, то стучите в саппорт хоста на предмет поддержки mysqli.

**upd.:**

Очевидцы пишут, что в некоторых случаях такая проблема возникает при использовании спецсимволов в пароле.

Comment: пароль очень простой, только цифры, поменял config.php но проблема всё равно та же, в момент переноса сайта когда попытался в админку зайти то писало что время токена вышло что то такое

Comment: тогда обновите кеш браузера, сотрите кеши модификаторовов (тут описано как - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706756/Работа-с-opencart-cms)

Comment: спасибо, но не в браузере проблема а в самом сайте потому что я  это делал и открывал с других компов не помогает...забавно устанавливал опенкарт на тотже хост и есть возможность войти в админпанель а при переносе нужного сайта и настроике то не могу войти ... может какая то проблема с базой данных или разрешений там 777 или 755 ? хотя маловероятно  скорей с базой что то но как понять что

Comment: вы переписали конфиги под новый домен? базы?

Comment: Да переписал и установил опенкарт тестовый что бы проверить если правильно и скопировал конфиги все ок вроде но не работает

Comment: фронт при этом работает нормально?

Comment: да, работает нормально

Comment: Если переустановили по новой, в ходе инстала должны были прописывать админа. По нему тоже не входит? И переносили ли саму базу? Юзеры храняться в ней.

Comment: установил тествоый опенкарт на новый хост для проверки прописки, оказалось всё правильно,

Comment: я так и не понял в чём была проблема я скачивал базу данных в 2 режимах, быстрая и обычная... в итоге у меня на хостинге 2 возможных драйвера mysql и mysqli, работал и так и так, в 3 раз перезаписи базы данных всё заработало ...честно не знаю в чём была проблема думаю хост не получал все данные при закачке базы данных

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой на oc 2.3.0.2

На хосте поддержка mysqli реализована - все работало как часы. Фронт так и продолжал работать, админка пересталу пускать. в логах ничего аномального.
После замены драйвера с mysqli на mysql - пустило. Заменил снова на mysqli - все продолжало нормально работать. Возможно какое-то обновление самой субд как-то повлияло на это. четкого ответа не нашел