# как убрать данный блок с соц сетями

Tags: cms, opencart

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать данный блок с соц сетями
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Найдите в шаблоне секцию

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
...
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

И удалите её полностью

Comment: Да я так сделал все равно на сайте не изчез

Answer (score 1):

Ищите в настройках вашего шаблона в админке, (не путать с настройками магазина -
первое обычно можно найти в модулях). Если у шаблона нет модуля управления, тогда смотрите в файле представления .tpl, в каком - хз, зависит от шаблона. Найдёте - удалите или закомментируйте. Снесите кеш расширений ([объяснял тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706756/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-opencart-cms/707527#707527)).

Answer (score 1):

Если удалили его из файла, а он все равно остался)
Попробуйте обновить модификаторы.